# Jenkins Shared lib not working properly

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

Recently I tried to add Shared Libraries to my Jenkins instance to make it easier to maintain all code that runs in each project.

1. I have a repo `myorg/jenkins`

Inside of it I have Jenkinsfile and groovy file meant to contain libraries, Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```java
@Library('utils@develop')_
import com.*

jenkinsSlave = "slave.myorg.com"

node(jenkinsSlave) {
    stage('Test') {
        def var = "kek"
        myorg.echoTest(var)
    }
}
```

I try to execute `echoTest` method there and I'm passing one argument.

Shared libs look like this (Jenkinsfile is in root directory of this repo):

```
src
└── com
    └── myorg
        └── Utils.groovy
```

Utils.groovy:

```java
#!/usr/bin/groovy
package com.myorg


def echoTest(test) {
  println("Test + ${test}")
}

return this
```

In Jenkins I've added this repo to global libraries section and I pointed to main branch, which is develop in this case.

Unfortuantely, when I run build jenkins throws this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myorg for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checke

[...]
```

I tried various configuration but so far I cannot make this work. I've tried to follow few tutorials about implementing this and I cannot pass through here.

Does someone notice any misconfiguration in this setup?

Answer (score 1):

You have not instantiated the Utils class in the myorg classpath so you cannot reference the method `echoTest()`. Try `Utils.echoTest` or just `echoTest()`

Answer (score 0):

When you see `scriptsecurity.sandbox` error, that means you need to allow the script from Jenkins script approval page https:///scriptApproval/
Also I would recommend you not to import your package directly within your pipeline. Instead I would define a step under `./vars` folder and only there import the custom package

Comment: Shared libraries are considered trusted and would not throw a sandbox error. See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries for more details.